# Find equations such that the solution space is the Image of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $T$ is a linear transformation such that
$(x_1, x_2, x_3) \mapsto (3x_1 + 4x_2 + 2x_3, x_1 + 2x_2, 2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3, -x_1 + 5x_2 - 7x_3)$

Find a homogeneous system of equation such that $\text{Image}(T) = \text{Solution space to this system}$.

Attempt at a solution: I know that the solution to a homogeneous system is the *Kernel* of the transformation $R(v) = A\cdot v$ where $A$ is the matrix representing the system of equations and $v = (x_1,...,x_n)$ (Column vector).

So I tried putting the above equations for the transformation $T$ into a matrix and row reducing it to obtain a basis for the $\text{Image}(T)$.

Then using the fact that Basis of $\text{Image}(T) = \text{Basis of Solution space}$, I tried to reverse engineer the basis to yield $2$ equations. However I've not had much success with this and am not sure how to check whether my answer is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $T$ is of the form $T(\vec x)=A\vec x$ where 
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 3 \\
-1 & 5 & -7
\end{array}\right]
$$
The image of $T$ is the column space of $A$. Row reducing $A^\top$ gives $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}$
$$
\rref A^\top=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{11}{5} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{19}{5}
\end{array}\right]
$$
The rows of $\rref A^\top$ form a basis for the image of $T$. In particular, the image of $T$ is a three-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$. Note that each basis vector is orthogonal to
$$
v=
\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{11}{5}&0&\frac{19}{5}&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus the image of $T$ is exactly the solution space of the "system" of equations 
$$
-\frac{11}{5}\,x_1+\frac{19}{5}\,x_3+x_4=0
$$